# How can I hide a shipping option if that option is available as flat-rate or free?

Tags: shipping, ce-1.6.2.0

My store has UPS Ground available at a Flat-Rate for most orders, but customers are selecting the normal UPS Ground service.  I'm not sure how to make it so that the normal ground option is not available if the order is eligible for Flat-Rate or Free shipping.

Comment: What are the conditions for flat rate and free shipping?

Comment: @Amasty Flat rate applies to all orders, with a shipping restriction that disables it for orders over a certain weight.  Free applies to orders over a certain dollar amount, with the same restriction for weight.  We actually use your extension for the shipping restrictions

Comment: David, then the life is easy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the custom module `shipping restrictions` is in the system, you can create an a new rule to disable just ground shipping from UPS method. Note, you don't need to select the UPS carrier as it disables ALL ups methods, not just ground.

[image: Restrict Ground Shipping]

Comment: That is exactly what I was missing...I thought to disable ground I would have to select all UPS.  I will try this and accept if it works

Comment: @David Nice :) , next time email us in the support as I have a vacation and not likely visit the site.