# Shipping methods issue. Free delivery and standard delivery. When it's "free" I want "standard delivery" to be disabled

Tags: magento-1, delivery

Is there a setting I could use to disable all the other shipping methods when free delivery shipping method kicks in? I have set an amount for free delivery to kick in and it's just stupid to display standard delivery method when free is available.

I have checked the standard delivery table rates, but it goes by the weight and not order amount. I have also tried to specify price vs. destination. But that option is not working well for me since my delivery partner ships product by weight.

Answer (score 1):

You may disable free shipping method in the setting AND enable it with shopping cart rule for some order amount.

Alternatively take a look at this answer [How can I hide a shipping option if that option is available as flat-rate or free?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/30443/how-can-i-hide-a-shipping-option-if-that-option-is-available-as-flat-rate-or-fre)

Answer (score 1):

A resolve by extending class `Mage_Model_Quote_Address`.
There is the `getGroupedAllShippingRates` function that fetches all available shipping rates. You may want to check if the original code I've used from `getGroupedAllShippingRates` matches what you have in your Magento version.

```
/**
 * Retrieve all grouped shipping rates
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getGroupedAllShippingRates()
{
    $rates = array();

    /* added code */
    $found = false;
    $collection = $this->getShippingRatesCollection();
    foreach ($collection as $rate) {
        if (!$rate->isDeleted() && $rate->getCarrierInstance()) {
            if ($rate->getCarrier() == "freeshipping" /*&& $rate->getMethod() == "freeshipping"*/) {
                $found = true;
            }
        }

    }

    foreach ($collection as $rate) {
        if (!$rate->isDeleted() && $rate->getCarrierInstance()) {
            if (!isset($rates[$rate->getCarrier()])) {
                $rates[$rate->getCarrier()] = array();
            }

            /* added code */
            $storeId = $this->getQuote()->getStoreId();
            switch ($storeId) {
                case 1: // my store -> default store
                    // any order that is not free shipping -> ignore
                    if ($found && !($rate->getCarrier() == "freeshipping" /*&& $rate->getMethod() == "freeshipping"*/)) {
                        continue 2;
                    }
                    break;
            }

            $rates[$rate->getCarrier()][] = $rate;
            $rates[$rate->getCarrier()][0]->carrier_sort_order = $rate->getCarrierInstance()->getSortOrder();
        }
    }
    uasort($rates, array($this, '_sortRates'));
    return $rates;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do price vs destination, which would solve your problem, as you wouldn't need to enable "Free shipping" in shipping methods.

[image]

Comment: it's not a good solution for me. I want the shipment price to goes by weight since this price is synced with my logistics partner and they ship by weight.

Comment: I'm sorry but at the time of reading your edit I had already answered.(time to change language, make screenshot etc etc ^^)

Comment: have you tried Owebia Shipping? It's a pretty advanced solution for custom rates on shipping.