# Restrict shipping methods to certain products

Tags: shipping, shipping-methods

Most of my business is books, so usps media mail is my main shipping method. I recently started selling other products as well, is there a way for magento to only display usps media mail for orders that are books only?

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict some shipping methods based on product conditions as described here: [How can I hide a shipping option if that option is available as flat-rate or free?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/30443/how-can-i-hide-a-shipping-option-if-that-option-is-available-as-flat-rate-or-fre)

Comment: How do I get to that screen where I'm able to make shipping rules?

Comment: The screen goes from the discussed extension *shipping restrictions*. You can find it (or similar) at the magento connect.  There is no build in restictions in magento I'm afraid.